# Ubuntu Server 20.04 - the installer was restarted because of an error

Tags: server, system-installation, 20.04

I'm trying to do a fresh installation of 20.04 server using ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso but i keep getting a "sorry the installer was restarted because of an error"

[sorry the installer was restarted because of an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehYUv.png)

I saw there was an email yesterday about this:

> Shortly after the release of Ubuntu 20.04.2, on Thursday February 4 2021,
> a regression was discovered which means that on certain systems and under
> certain specific conditions the Ubuntu installer can fail to install a Linux
> kernel. This renders the system unable to boot.

> After carefully analysing the impact of this regression, the release team took
> the decision to reissue images of 20.04.2 with a corrected version of the
> installer. These images are now available, versioned as 20.04.2.0. Only the
> Ubuntu flavours listed below are affected. If you have downloaded the 20.04.2
> release of any of these flavours, we encourage you to re-download the updated
> versions.

But the server image date is on the 4th vs the desktop image is from the 11th

[iso image listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pyx1i.png)

Comment: What you quote (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-February/000265.html) refers to Ubuntu 20.04.2 Desktop & most *flavors* (but not all), and does not impact Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Server.  Did you verify your ISO before writing to media?  (the issue related to `ubiquity` ISOs, not `calamares` used by Lubuntu, or `subiquity` used by Ubuntu *live* Server)

Comment: Yeap I did:                                               echo "d1f2bf834bbe9bb43faf16f9be992a6f3935e65be0edece1dee2aa6eb1767423 *ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso" | shasum -a 256 --check                  
ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso: OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why but I tried again after unmounting/remounting the iso image from the HP ilo and it worked, apologies for this.